# Android Studio-Failed to resolve:com.android.support:appcompat-v7.22.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I imported project from Github and there's error:
[image]

I have already update SDK manager with Android Support Respository and Android Support Library:
[image]

Comment: Instead of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7.22.2.0` use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7.23.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

> I have already update SDK manager with Android Support Respository and Android Support Library

If you look at that picture, you will notice that you are on version 14 of the Android Support Repository. Please update the Android Support Repository to the latest version. That should allow you to add `22.2.0` of `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: I just update to the latest version, but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Fix simple. Click link **Install Repository and sync project** and continue install.

Not click **Show In file**

Not click  **Show In project structure dialog**

**This diferent links.**